# Sails.js Dynamically Switching Database based on users

Tags: database, orm, adapter, sails.js, waterline

I am currently building a project that requires switching between different databases according to the user logged in.

Every registered user has it's own database however the tables (the structure) within the databases are the same.

e.g. user login by authenticating at the default database, if true then get the databaseName from the default database accordingly and then connect to that database from then on.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: spring has a way to do it using `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. am not sure if you using spring here.